# This Dynamic Query code, where is the problem(php)?

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic-sql

I have this codes for Dynamic Query on a search box but i don't have any result for a search word(this word must return several records) while i have output for string($q),appreciate that help me for finding the problem.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

//include("../mahal/mahal.php"); 
include("../mahal/mahalmag.php");

$textfieldstring = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Textfield1']);

$connmag = mysql_connect($dbhostmag, $dbusermag, $dbpassmag) or die ('Error connecting to Database,this is maybe due to heavy traffic,please refresh your page.'); 
$dbname = 'magazine';
mysql_select_db("$dbname");
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8',$connmag);  //for utf charachter 

$q = strip_tags(trim($textfieldstring));

if($q) {
      $search_words = explode(' ', strtolower($q));

      for($i = 0; $i < count($search_words); $i++) {
            if($i) {
                  $str_search .= "OR title LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_words[$i])."%' OR articlebody LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_words[$i])."%' ";
            } else {
                  $str_search = "OR title LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_words[$i])."%' OR articlebody LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_words[$i])."%' ";
            }
      }
}
$search_data = "WHERE (".$str_search.")";

$query_search = "SELECT a.articleid, a.title, a.state, SUBSTR(a.articlebody,1,300) AS description1, 
      p.photofilename, a.deletitem, ac.catid,c.parentid,a.articlebody
    FROM tbarticles a
      INNER JOIN tbphotos p ON (p.articleid = a.articleid)
      INNER JOIN tbarticlecategories ac ON (ac.articleid =  a.articleid)
      INNER JOIN tbcategories c ON (c.catid = ac.catid)
    $search_data AND a.deletitem = '1'";

$result_search = mysql_query($query_search);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result_search);
$query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_search);
echo "$num_rows";
echo "$q";
?>
```

Update: the extra "OR" has been removed from the case where `$i` is 0.

When the search term is (for example) "cold", the generated SQL query is:

```
SELECT a.articleid, a.title, a.state, SUBSTR(a.articlebody,1,100) AS description1,
       p.photofilename, a.deletitem, ac.catid,c.parentid,a.articlebody 
  FROM tbarticles a 
    INNER JOIN tbphotos p ON (p.articleid = a.articleid) 
    INNER JOIN tbarticlecategories ac ON (ac.articleid = a.articleid) 
    INNER JOIN tbcategories c ON (c.catid = ac.catid) 
  WHERE ( title LIKE '%cold%' OR articlebody LIKE '%cold%' ) 
    AND a.deletitem = '1'
```

With a search term of "cold play", the query is:

```
SELECT a.articleid, a.title, a.state, SUBSTR(a.articlebody,1,100) AS description1, 
       p.photofilename, a.deletitem, ac.catid,c.parentid,a.articlebody 
  FROM tbarticles a 
    INNER JOIN tbphotos p ON (p.articleid = a.articleid) 
    INNER JOIN tbarticlecategories ac ON (ac.articleid = a.articleid) 
    INNER JOIN tbcategories c ON (c.catid = ac.catid) 
  WHERE ( title LIKE '%cold%' OR articlebody LIKE '%cold%' 
       OR title LIKE '%play%' OR articlebody LIKE '%play%' ) 
    AND a.deletitem = '1' but lot of records are not related to search word
```

Comment: It would be very easy to debug this if you would `echo $query_search` also it would be better to do something like `if ($i > 0) {` :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to strip the first OR from $str_search

```
  $search_data = "WHERE (".$str_search.")";
```

The code should have been

```
  $str_search = '';
  for($i = 0; $i < count($search_words); $i++) {
        if($i) { $str_search .= " OR "; }
        $str_search .= " title LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_words[$i])."%' OR articlebody LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_words[$i])."%' ";
  }
```

To make it match multiple $search_words where all words must exist in a single articlebody or a single title, then

```
  $str_search_article = '';
  $str_search_title = '';
  for($i = 0; $i < count($search_words); $i++) {
        if($i) {
            $str_search_article .= " AND ";
            $str_search_title .= " AND ";
        }
        $search_word = "'%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_words[$i])."%'";
        $str_search_title .= " title LIKE " . $search_word;
        $str_search_article .= " articlebody LIKE " . $search_word;
  }
  $search_data = "WHERE ((".$str_search_title.") OR (".$str_search_article."))";
```

Comment: I tested,now i have result,but when i type suppose 2 words then the records has not relative to this search,ofcourse i search in arabic and at the top i have this code for utf-8

Comment: $textfieldstring = utf8_decode(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['Textfield1']));

Comment: i have relpace this part with your code ,is it right                                 for($i = 0; $i < count($search_words); $i++) {
            if($i) {
                  $str_search .= "OR title LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_words[$i])."%' OR articlebody LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_words[$i])."%' ";
            } else {
                  $str_search = "OR title LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_words[$i])."%' OR articlebody LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_words[$i])."%' ";
            }
      }

Comment: @Kaveh that is the original code again? add a `die($query_search)` somewhere to see the MySQL statement

Comment: @cyberkiwi,i don't know that how can i post my codes,please guide me,i copy past my codes but i see that i appear like this,but let me explain,i put your codes instead of the original,but there is 0 result for all search,with my code i don't have any result(echo "$num_rows";) .

Comment: for a word in arabic die is :SELECT a.articleid, a.title, a.state, SUBSTR(a.articlebody,1,100) AS description1, p.photofilename, a.deletitem, ac.catid,c.parentid,a.articlebody FROM tbarticles a INNER JOIN tbphotos p ON (p.articleid = a.articleid) INNER JOIN tbarticlecategories ac ON (ac.articleid = a.articleid) INNER JOIN tbcategories c ON (c.catid = ac.catid) WHERE ( title LIKE '%�����%' OR articlebody LIKE '%�����%' ) AND a.deletitem = '1'

Comment: for word of 'cold' die is : "SELECT a.articleid, a.title, a.state, SUBSTR(a.articlebody,1,100) AS description1, p.photofilename, a.deletitem, ac.catid,c.parentid,a.articlebody FROM tbarticles a INNER JOIN tbphotos p ON (p.articleid = a.articleid) INNER JOIN tbarticlecategories ac ON (ac.articleid = a.articleid) INNER JOIN tbcategories c ON (c.catid = ac.catid) WHERE ( title LIKE '%cold%' OR articlebody LIKE '%cold%' ) AND a.deletitem = '1'

Comment: @Kaveh - You can post code by updating the question. But the query looks correct - if you run it using phpmyadmin/mysql workbench/console, does it give any results?

Comment: for 'cold play' ,die is :SELECT a.articleid, a.title, a.state, SUBSTR(a.articlebody,1,100) AS description1, p.photofilename, a.deletitem, ac.catid,c.parentid,a.articlebody FROM tbarticles a INNER JOIN tbphotos p ON (p.articleid = a.articleid) INNER JOIN tbarticlecategories ac ON (ac.articleid = a.articleid) INNER JOIN tbcategories c ON (c.catid = ac.catid) WHERE ( title LIKE '%cold%' OR articlebody LIKE '%cold%' OR title LIKE '%play%' OR articlebody LIKE '%play%' ) AND a.deletitem = '1'                       but lot of records are not related to search word.

Comment: For `cold play` do you want only where `both` words are found? Both words in the same articlebody or title, or match if `cold` is found in body and `play` is found in title?

Comment: i can test it in Query Browser,but because the WHERE  code is a variable how can i test it in Query Browser?

Comment: Both words in the same articlebody or title.

Comment: @Kaveh - you test it by using the output from die($query)

Comment: 'cold OR play OR both' in title    OR   'cold OR play or both' in articlebody .

Comment: @Kaveh - If you have OR everywhere like that, then a single "play" in articlebody will show the entire record.

Comment: @cyberkiwi - i tested for one word die for cold is:   SELECT a.articleid, a.title, a.state, SUBSTR(a.articlebody,1,100) AS description1, p.photofilename, a.deletitem, ac.catid,c.parentid,a.articlebody FROM tbarticles a INNER JOIN tbphotos p ON (p.articleid = a.articleid) INNER JOIN tbarticlecategories ac ON (ac.articleid = a.articleid) INNER JOIN tbcategories c ON (c.catid = ac.catid) WHERE (( title LIKE %".mysql_real_escape_string($search_words[$i])."%) OR ( articlebody LIKE %".mysql_real_escape_string($search_words[$i])."%)) AND a.deletitem = '1'       no result

Comment: @kaveh - please try again, it was missing two double quotes

Comment: @cyberkiwi-Please you guide me that which one is better,and select the code yourself,i want a simple and good search for user.

Comment: @cyberkiwi-the system does not alow me to post die because limitation in character,but result is like previous.

Comment: RE: posting as an answer: only if it answers the question. The information posted above should be edited into the question, as it's a clarification of the question. Note that rather than testing whether the loop body is in it's first iteration, you could (a) store the conditions in an array and `implode` them or (b) start with an initial `1=0` condition, which will always be false and thus won't affect the query results (if you were taking the conjunction of the conditions with `AND`, you'd use `1=1` as an initial condition). Of the two, I recommend (a), as it involves fewer memory alloc ops.

Comment: @cyberkiwi -did you receive the die for cold?